# repeats the value in one column to fill the empty cells in that column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe like this:

```
A  B
a
a  
a  b
a
a  
a  B
```

I want to fill the empty cells in the column "B" with the existing values in "B". so that the end result will be:

```
A  B
a  b
a  b
a  b
a  B
a  B
a  B
```

I have tried the idea to get the column "B" in a pandas series and remove the empty cells.

```
tmp=df['B']
tmp.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True, how=None)
```

Then I want to repeat each item in the tmp series three times and put it back to the origianl dataframe. But failed.

My solution may not be a good one. Any suggestion could help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df["B"] = df["B"].bfill()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find duplicate, so use `bfill` only if empty values are missing values in some column:

```
df["B"] = df["B"].replace('', np.nan).bfill()
```

Comment: Hello, I accepted your answer. But then I found out another column in my dataframe that I want to the same process actually have duplicates. That column is: ``` "", "c", "","c","", "C", "","d"``` The bfill() does not work very well there. Do you mind give some inputs for that? Thanks!

Comment: @Catherine - Another solution not working?

Comment: You mean ```df.replace('', np.nan).bfill()```.  I want specify a specific column and backfill. Is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: @Catherine answer was edited

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the empty strings with `replace`, then use `bfill`, backward fill:

```
>>> df.replace('', np.nan).bfill()
   A  B
0  a  b
1  a  b
2  a  b
3  a  B
4  a  B
5  a  B
>>>
```